# Cannot authorize Watson assistant audio client

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson-assistant-solutions

I am developing a simple audio client for Watson assistant solutions and I am having problems authorizing the client.

I am following this guide https://watson-personal-assistant.github.io/developer/audio/audio_authentication/ but the Api Key I am using is not recognized. 
The error message I get is the following:

```
"errorMessage": "Provided API key could not be found"
```

The Api Key I am using is the one displayed in the user's card (that appears  when clicking the user's avatar in the top-right corner of the page).

In the console there is the Clients tab which states:

> A client can be a device such as a smart speaker or wearable, but it could also be a mobile app or web-based chatbot. Use this page to create credentials for those clients and assign an entity to them.

I thought that an Api Key could be created here, but it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Watson Assistant Solutions Service is now using IAM API key instead of the API key for the MultiTenant Audio Gateway. This does pre-req that you have a [An IBM Cloud ID account](https://console.bluemix.net/dashboard/apps/)

1. To create your own IBM IAM API key use these directions https://console.bluemix.net/docs/iam/userid_keys.html#userapikey
2. You also need your tenant id you can find that in the WASol Console.

[image]

3. Your client will have to send the following properties

   ## Server connection parameterss. For userID note to not include ( @ # . or other special chars).  There is an issue we are fixing.

   ```
   host=wa-audio-gateway.mybluemix.net
   userID=carlos.ferreira
   ```

   ## IAM API Key is Used to authenticate the client device

   ```
   IAMAPIKey=yourIAMAPIkey
   ```

   ## Choosing which skill set to use (Required parameter)

   ```
   skillset=industry
   ```

   ## Your tenant ID (Required parameter)

   ```
   tenantID=yourtenantID
   ```

   ## Client language specific preferences can be passed (Optional parameter with a default value: en-US)

   ```
   language=en-US
   ```

   ## Choosing which STT and TTS engine to convert audio to text and text to audio - possible values are : watson, google , (Optional parameter with a default value : watson)

   ```
   engine=google
   ```

   ## Controls playback method. Playback using an audio URL in the response [true], playback by streaming audio from the server [false]

   ```
   urltts=false
   ```

   4. You can find a reference Java implementation for the Audio Gateway here. https://github.com/Watson-Personal-Assistant/AudioClientSampleCodeJava

Please note that you also need to use IBM APIKey for programmatic access to the WASol Core text routing service.  Here is a [code example](https://github.com/fe01134/alexa-speak-with-assistant/blob/master/src/flask-ask/was_core.py) I did to get Amazon Dot/Alexa skill to communicate with WASol Assistant skill set.